# dhtmlxscheduler with Aurelia and typescript

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I'm trying to install `dhtmlxscheduler` to my Aurelia CLI (typescript) app. I've npm installed it:

```
npm i dhtmlx-scheduler
```

Then I added it to the `aurelia.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "dhtmlx-scheduler",
  "path": "../node_modules/dhtmlx-scheduler/codebase",
  "main": "dhtmlxscheduler"
},
```

And created the global typings for it:

```
typings install dt~dhtmlxscheduler --global --save
```

everything installed and `au run` compiles correctly. When I try to actually use the the library though I get this error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'dhtmlxscheduler'.
[02:00:15] gulp-notify: [Error running Gulp] Error: src/components/appointments/appointments.ts(2,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'dhtmlxscheduler'.
```

I'm importing it like so:

```
import * as scheduler from 'dhtmlxscheduler';
```

Comment: Try changing `import * as scheduler from 'dhtmlxscheduler';` to `import * as scheduler from 'dhtmlx-scheduler';`. The Aurelia CLI Github [page](https://github.com/aurelia/cli#user-content-a-single-file-module) states that the value given to "name" should be the same value used in the import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into dhtmlxscheduler.js and it doesn't [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) any member properties. Doing `import * as scheduler from 'dhtmlxscheduler';` should give you an error.

Instead, [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) the entire module:

```
import 'dhtmlx-scheduler'; // Taking into account the comment that I left above
```

Then you can call the `scheduler` function directly in your class.

Answer (score 1):

It works with the import statement from @Robinson Collado. You might want to add the dhtmlx-gantt css file as resource:

```
{
  "name": "dhtmlx-gantt",
  "path": "../node_modules/dhtmlx-gantt/codebase",
  "main": "dhtmlxgantt",
  "resources": [
    "dhtmlxgantt.css"
  ]
}
```

and include it in your template:

```
<require from="dhtmlx-gantt/dhtmlxgantt.css"></require>
```